# Invalid rackup file with Foreman gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreman, rackup

Trying to run foreman start on vagrant (Ubuntu).

Procfile

```
web:            bundle exec thin start --port 3000
private_pub:    bundle exec thin start --port 9292 --rackup private_pub.ru
```

private_pub.ru is under my root directory, so does Procfile.

If I do this (it works):

```
rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production
```

and after rails server...

But when I do this:

```
foreman start

20:43:18 web.1          | started with pid 3447
20:43:18 private_pub.1  | started with pid 3450
20:43:20 private_pub.1  | /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:183:in `load_rackup_config': Invalid rackup file.  please specify either a .ru or .rb file (RuntimeError)
20:43:20 private_pub.1  |       from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:71:in `start'
20:43:20 private_pub.1  |       from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:185:in `run_command'
20:43:20 private_pub.1  |       from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:151:in `run!'
20:43:20 private_pub.1  |       from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/thin-1.3.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
20:43:20 private_pub.1  |       from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/thin:19:in `load'
20:43:20 private_pub.1  |       from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
20:43:20 private_pub.1  | process terminated
20:43:20 system         | sending SIGTERM to all processes
20:43:20 system         | sending SIGTERM to pid 3447
20:43:25 system         | sending SIGKILL to all processes
20:43:25 system         | sending SIGKILL to pid 3447
```

Comment: I have a feeling it had to do with my virtual machine, because it works under Mac Os.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with Vagrant. Your Procfile (cloned under windows) has Windows line endings (\r\n). This makes thin see 'private_pub.ru\r' as its rackup file due to the newline at the end of the file, so the test here: https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/blob/master/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb#L176 fails.

Remove the newline to solve the problem.